# Google doc Embed Issue

Tags: iframe, powerpoint, embed, google-docs

I am using https://docs.google.com/gview?url=file to view a PPT in my webpage. While this works fine in a new window, when I try to access via an iFrame, it is not working. It throws a console error saying "Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."
But inspite of changing xframe options to deny as well as sameorigin, it still doesn;t work. Please help. Microsoft office viewer is not displaying the document at all.
Thanks for any help

https://docs.google.com/gview?url=filenaem